# Corinis/JSFORM : nested collections are ignored

Tags: json, collections, nested, jsform

I'm using Corinis/jsForm.js (jquery.jsForm-1.0.rc.2.js) to map JSON to/from html fields

I have trouble when my collection is deeply nested
(i.e. the field seems to get ignored)

any suggestions ?

My json object looks like this

```
{ "@class" : "CmsNode",
  "@fieldTypes" : "createdOn=t,updatedOn=t",
  "@rid" : "#13:16",
  "@type" : "d",
  "@version" : 18,
  "children" : [  ],
  "cmsRecord" : { "@class" : "CmsRecord",
      "@type" : "d",
      "@version" : 0,
      "active" : [ { "@class" : "Record",
            "@type" : "d",
            "@version" : 0,
            "properties" : { "alias" : "blah" }
          } ],
      "archive" : [  ],
      "classifications" : [  ],
      "keywords" : [  ],
      "pending" : [  ]
    },
  "createdOn" : "2013-07-05 12:38:59:057",
  "data" : { "name" : "test3en" },
  "history" : [  ],
  "isMenu" : true,
  "isVisible" : false,
  "mvcModel" : "dd",
  "mvcView" : "aaa",
  "pageViews" : [  ],
  "parents" : [ "#13:9" ],
  "related" : [  ],
  "updatedOn" : "2013-07-08 09:06:47:610",
  "uuid" : "933a10da-b9a8-44d1-9a65-adc189c740b2",
  "viewClasses" : [  ]
}
```

I need to have an input field attached to property `data.cmsRecord.active.properties.alias`

I'm trying to achieve this, by using the following html code:

```
<div class="collection" data-field="data.cmsRecord.active"> 
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="active.properties.alias" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by the script author.

fixed Release: jsForm-1.0.3.js